# Filling in the Area between of two lines which intersect?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Is it possible to fill in the area between a Dataset plotting a XY line and a ValueMarker ?
See picture for the general idea(Warning: My MS Paint skills are lacking).

[image]

Comment: Do you know integration?

Comment: The most similar renderer is **[XYDifferenceRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYDifferenceRenderer.html)**

Comment: @ Trevor Arjeski, yes i do and  lschin , ill take a look at that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lschin, XYDifferenceRenderer is the best way to do this. In order to have this work you need to create two separate multidimensional double arrays to store to X and Y coordinates. The first array is set to store your a XY line's x and y coor's. The second array is a constant XY line. To set this line up you X values are the same. If your original line is above your constant line, the Y value is the coordinate you choose of position of the constant line. If the original is below the constant then the Y value of the constant is that of your original line. I hope that makes sense and is helpful to anyone, ive attached code below for better understanding.

setConstant = position of your constant line.
The code below is placed in a loop:

```
indLine[0][i]= XYIndLine.getXValue(1, i);
indLine[1][i] = XYIndLine.getYValue(1, i);
constant[0][i] = XYIndLine.getXValue(1, i);
constant[1][i] = Math.min(setConstant, XYIndLine.getYValue);
```

once this is done then use addSeries to add the two arrays to a DefaultXYDataset